# how do i use 'from utils import sentence'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from utils import sentence
sentences = sentence.Iterator(train_items,train_playlist, sentence.Mode.ALBUM)
```

I want to use 'sentence', but when I execute the code, an error appears. The error is as follows.

ImportError: cannot import name 'sentence' from 'utils' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/utils/**init**.py)

python version: 3.7
utils version: 1.0.1

Comment: Are you certain that the library actually contains something named `sentence`?

Comment: ImportError clearly says there is no such module in the package. Either a mistake or lib structure has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `from utils.sentence import Iterator` and then do `sentences = Iterator(...)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but, "No module named 'utils.sentence'"